# Как установить ru_listx в espeak или где находится dictsource папка ?

Tags: linux, tts

Скачала [отсюда](http://espeak.sourceforge.net/data/)  ru_dict-48 зипку. Пишут что прежде чем скомпилировать файлы с этой зипки, нужно скопировать их в dictsource директорию.

**Вопрос** : А где находится эта директория ?

Команда `whereis espeak` выдаёт всего :

/usr/bin/espeak - тут исполняемый elf файл.
/usr/share/man/man1/espeak.1.gz - тут мануал.

Answer (score 0):

Если не известно, какие каталоги программа открывает-загружает при старте попробуйте посмотреть ее трейс (работает в GNU/Linux):

```
~$ strace /use/bin/espeak -f file 2>1 | grep open
```

Смотрим что в пакете, какие пути будут использоватся по умолчанию:

```
~$ dpkg-query -L espeak # debian/Ubuntu
~$ rpm -ql espeak # centos/fedora
```

можно глянуть исходники, в в частности Makefile:

*trunc/src/Makefile*

```
...
DATADIR=/usr/share/espeak-data

PREFIX=/usr
BINDIR=$(PREFIX)/bin
INCDIR=$(PREFIX)/include/espeak
LIBDIR=$(PREFIX)/lib

...
install: all
    # Create directories
    rm -rf $(DESTDIR)$(DATADIR)
    $(MKDIR) $(DESTDIR)$(BINDIR)
    $(MKDIR) $(DESTDIR)$(LIBDIR)
    $(MKDIR) $(DESTDIR)$(INCDIR)
    $(MKDIR) $(DESTDIR)$(DATADIR)
...
```

Разработчики espeack советуют переходить на espeak-ng

**Ссылки**

- https://github.com/espeak-ng/espeak-ng/
- https://sourceforge.net/p/espeak/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/src/Makefile#l3